# Can xml markup be included in an internal entity declaration?

Tags: xml, entity

I want to define an entity containing XML markup similar to the following in my XML document.

```
<testElm testAtt="attValue">Only a test.</testElm>
```

Is it possible to do this with an internal entity? Will I have to resort to an external entity? What is the best practice when declaring entities that contain XML markup?

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded XML doesn't need to be parsed by the XML parser, I would wrap it inside a CDATA section, which causes it to be ignored by the parser.

```
<![CDATA[<testElm testAtt="attValue">Only a test.</testElm>]]>
```